# (Unity XR Toolkit) Interactable priority

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, interaction, toolkit

I need to make my pistol slide interactable always prioritised over grabbing the pistol itself. Is there any system for prioritising certain interactable over others in place?

Alternatively, does anyone know how I could prevent the pistol itself from being grabbed twice when it is already held? I have "Single" select mode, yet my secondary hand can still momentarily grab it before the interaction is cancelled... (I still get haptic and auditory feedback that an interaction has occurred)